# Enum.Parse Error

Tags: c#, parsing, enums

I'm trying to change a the chart type for a series by using a variable. Here's what I have.

```
Graph.Series[SeriesName.Text].ChartType = Enum.Parse(SeriesChartType, GraphType.Name);
```

Although I get an error which is

> 'SeriesChartType' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

How can I fix this? I am using

> using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change like this,

```
Graph.Series[SeriesName.Text].ChartType = Enum.Parse(typeof(SeriesChartType), GraphType.Name);
```

Comment: When I do that I get `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1769562.aspx?Cannot+implicitly+convert+type+Chart+SeriesChartType+to+System+Web+UI+DataVisualization+Charting+SeriesChartType+An+explicit+conversion+exists+are+you+missing+a+cast+

Comment: Seems like making it `Graph.Series[SeriesName.Text].ChartType = (SeriesChartType)Enum.Parse(typeof(SeriesChartType), GraphType.Text);` made it work. Thanks.